# MiniMaxApproximation not working in Mathematica 7

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to obtain a minimax rational function approximation to a certain expression. In particular, I'm using

```
mma = MiniMaxApproximation[x^2, {x, {8, 10}, 2, 2}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica 7 replies with the same expression I'm trying to calculate, namely

```
MiniMaxApproximation[x^2, {x, {8, 10}, 2, 2}]
```

Of course, I'm aware this is a very simple test, since `x^2` is the rational function approximation of itself.

I'm also trying other possibilities like RationalInterpolation, EconomizedRationalApproximation etc., but none is working. Only PadeApproximant returns a result.

Anyone has an idea on why this happens?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

likely your first problem is that you havent loaded the function approximation package,
start a new kernel and try this:

```
Needs["FunctionApproximations`"]
mma = MiniMaxApproximation[Exp[x], {x, {0, 1}, 1, 2}]
```

Your specific example (x^2) throws a slew of (to me) nonsensical errors. I guess MiniMaxApproximation is not robust in handling trivial degenerate cases.

---

evidently requesting a numerator equal to the order for your expression is causing the error:

```
a[x_] = MiniMaxApproximation[x^2, {x, {8, 10}, 1, 2}][[2, 1]]
Plot[ {a[x]  , x^2}, {x, -10, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much george. Not loading the package was the mistake of  the question of a very Mathematica beginner. I will check MiniMaxApproximation and also the other rational function approximation possibilities and possibly post questions.